# Salesforce "Company Communities" Release Date

Tags: community

I thought Salesforce was going to release ["Company Communities"](http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2013/05/130530.jsp) at the end of 2013, but I haven't seen any release announcements since. Does anyone know the planned launch date?

Answer (score 7):

They're out - see the "Editions and Pricing" section of the [Communities marketing page](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/communities/) and the [W'14 Release Notes description of the new user license](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_sitecom_company_comm_license.htm) and [Permission Set license](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_sitecom_company_comm_PermSet.htm).

Answer (score -1):

+1 Thomas

Communities are released. If you were using portals earlier then you can convert them into communities now. but if you need new licenses you can contact your Account Exec and they'll issue licenses to you

Comment: The question was about Company Communities, which were announced after the initial Communities release, and represent a new license type.